# Javascript scrape clean up - TMview

Tags: javascript

I scrape data for a database with a chrome extension, need assistance with a JavaScript clean up function.

Output is a .xls file that i run a javascript thru to remove unwanted data.

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuMlg.png)
I need to remove the the stand alone " - " in the rows that doesn't have any dates.

i've tried this solution - but it wont let me do it in more than 1 column.

```
    this.values[9] = this.values[9];
    let [day, month, year] = this.values[9].split("-");
    this.values[9] = this.values[9].replace("-","")
    this.values[9] = `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
```

This.values[9] = this.values[9]; is how i target in this case the application date row in the script

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
this.values[9] = this.values[9] == "-" ? "" : this.values[9];
```